# How to get only ids in @ManyToMany mapping, without referencing the whole object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am following the tutorial from baeldung:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

The first example is what I need:

[image]

The example shows how to add relationship in User class:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = "course_like", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
Set<Course> likedCourses;
```

The difference in my case is that I do not need to access the whole object when getting the data.
I only need to return the set of Ids.

**1.) I have tried the option with @ElementCollection:**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = "course_like", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
Set<Course> likedCourses;




@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
  name = "course_like", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
Set<Long> likedCourses;
```

**2.) Also, returning the whole object, iterating and storing ids in**,
and

**3.) There is a third option with @Transient and @PostLoad**

```
public Set<Course> likedCourses;

@Transient
public Set<Long> courseIds;

@PostLoad
private void postLoad() {
    courseIds = likedCourses.stream().map(Course::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**I am looking for the most optimized way, it seems to me option #3 is not good since it could call @Postload potentially more than once.**

How would you go about this? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest just writing a custom JPA or native query which selects only the column(s) you want.  This will avoid loading the entire entity.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about too.

So the class would have just this, right?
`@JsonIgnore @ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = "course_like", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
Set<Course> likedCourses;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM Student s JOIN s.likedCourses c
WHERE s.id = :id
```

However, I see that Hibernate generates an extra join with the courses table which is unfortunate. If you have problems with that, you can use a native SQL query as @TimBiegeleisen suggested.

Comment: Let's say you display a list of courses and enable the user to like or unlike a course. You need to check if student already liked certain courses, right? Which ones?
"In practice getting IDs only is pointless." I would say in theory getting IDs is pointless.
In practice, would you fetch the whole list of objects to check the state of liked/unliked courses for logged in student?

Comment: Also, why not simply: 
`SELECT c.id FROM course_like WHERE s.id = :id`

Comment: Indeed. I removed that part. You can do `SELECT ... FROM course_like` in JPQL only if you split the `@ManyToMany` relationship into two `@ManyToOne` with a dedicated `course_like` entity. With `@ManyToMany` there are no `course_like` entity to select from.